# How to change "Reset Password" text on submit button

Tags: password, reset

[image]
I want to change "Reset password" text on submit button to "Set password"

How can I change it?

I tried to change value with jQuery:

```
    add_action( 'resetpass_form', 'resettext');
    function resettext(){ ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">                 
            jQuery('#resetpassform input#wp-submit').val("Set Password");
    </script>
    <?php
    }
```

But it didn't work, I don't know why

Comment: Hi danibeiss, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 2):

I've added

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
```

and it works! Final working code below:

```
add_action( 'resetpass_form', 'resettext');
function resettext(){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {                 
     jQuery('#resetpassform input#wp-submit').val("Set Password");
   });
</script>
<?php
}
```